# How to retrieve the previous data into the textbox after deciding that you will not update the data?

Tags: .net, angular

I'm trying to make a cancel button that would clear the new inputted data from the user and return it to its old data using angular and localstorage.

I don't have a code yet because I don't know where to start.

I expect that after I will click the cancel button, it will then put back the original data whom I've clicked from the table.

Comment: <input type="reset">

Comment: <input type="reset"> sir will clear all the textfields. It's like a 'NEW' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you for example use a different component like a dialog, you can do it the other way round. Use a one-way binding '<' or @Input since angular2 and on submit either call a service to update or use @Output. If you want to implement a undo function with the cancel button, try to implement some kind of changelog/script.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question sir but still I don't get it. This is my first time to use angular and .NET. If you don't mind can you give me a simple example?